# Где и как лучше формировать JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

ситуация следующая. Есть определенный сайт, с которого я паршу данные. Парсер на nodejs (cheerio+axios).

Эти данные я сортирую по необходимому мне порядку, после чего ручками собираю json. Фактически, вариант данных, которые должны появляться на клиенте, и формируются на стадии сортировки.

Этот парсер, сам по себе, находится на сервере. На каждый гет-запрос, происходит парсинг страницы и формирование данных.

Где лучше парсить страницу: на самом сервере или создавать под это отдельную сущность?

Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативные варианты решения данной задачи?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: < Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативные варианты решения данной задачи?>


попробуй отловить запрос в network который отдает эти данные, если там обычный rest запрос, посмотри куда он уходит и дергай его, как правильно бэк с фронтом общается через JSON/xml (думаю библиотек для конверта xml to json уже куча)

если же используется серверный рендеринг, то этот вариант не подойдет

Comment: А вообще парсить другие сайты на самом сервере нормальная идея, или нет?